# MySQL Join and get all relations even if 0

Tags: mysql, join

I got two tables. One that holds all availeble trophys and one that holds the relation between user and trophy.

```
trophy
--------------------------------------
| trophy_id | name                   |
--------------------------------------
| 1         | kill 100 people        |
| 2         | kill 200 people        |
| 3         | fly 5000 feet upwards  |
| 4         | fly into a mountain    |
--------------------------------------

earned_trophys
------------------------------------------
| earned_trophy_id | trophy_id | user_id |
------------------------------------------
| 1                | 1         | 3       |
| 2                | 1         | 2       |
| 3                | 3         | 4       |
| 4                | 2         | 1       |
| 5                | 3         | 1       |
------------------------------------------
```

For example
User 1 has earned the kill 100 people and kill 200 people trophys.

I want a query that shows me something like this:

```
for user 1
-----------------------------
| kill 100 people       | 1 |
| kill 200 people       | 1 |
| fly 5000 feet upwards | 0 |
| fly into a mountain   | 0 |
-----------------------------
```

this is what I have tried:

```
select
    trophy.name,
    earned_trophys.user_id,  
    count(user_id) as temp
from
    trophy
left join
    earned_trophys
on
    trophy.trophy_id = earned_trophys.trophy_id
where
    earned_trophys.user_id = 1
group by
    name
```

but I only get the results for the things the user got, I want the temp = 0 rows to.
is it possible to do this in one query?

Comment: Left join is in-effective because for some other user who has user id != 1 has earned trophy 3 and 4. So move where condition in join clause it self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for left join to be in effect you need to move condition `earned_trophys.user_id = 1`  into the `on` clause  instead of `where`.

```
select
    trophy.name,
    earned_trophys.user_id,  
    count(user_id) as temp
from
    trophy
left join
    earned_trophys
on
    trophy.trophy_id = earned_trophys.trophy_id and earned_trophys.user_id = 1
group by
    name
```

Comment: Perfect fit for what I needed.  Yet again, I don't need to post a question on Stack because someone's already answered it!