# left join return null even if there are no rows

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

My tables:

Table `cat` has `id, name`

Table `user` has `id, uname, catid`

Sample data:
**cat table**

```
1 | Cate one
2 | cate two
```

**user table**

```
1 | sam | 1
2 | dam | 0
```

my query is

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.name 
FROM cat LEFT JOIN user 
  ON cat.id = user.catid
WHERE user.id = 2
```

Since there is no category with `id` 0 I get zero rows.
If there are no rows I want `NULL` or zeros as a result.

How do I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656483/mysql-join-and-get-all-relations-even-if-0

Comment: since i am not much into mysql i couldn't guess that...

Comment: this is a silly question. isn't it? anyway... since i am poor in mysql i had to ask such. besides the related questions are too huge to trial and error. so i asked a fresh one.

Comment: You should also consider implementing foreign key constraints. This would keep you from getting an invalid CAT ID since it would not allow you to add an id  that does not exist.

Comment: wow. that could too would add flavor in future for me. i had made a note of this. thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You either need to turn your left join into a right join or swap the tables around:

```
SELECT cat.id, cat.name
  FROM user LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.id = user.catid
 WHERE user.id = 2
```

With your example data, this will give you a row containing nulls as a result.

Comment: this is a silly question. isn't it? anyway... since i am poor in mysql i had to ask such. besides the related questions are too huge to trial and error. so i asked a fresh one.

Answer (score 6):

Change your `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN`... that should pull everything from the users table, and anything from the category table if it is available.

Comment: +1 -- It's why SQL has both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` flavours i.e. so the direction can be switched without having to "swap the tables around".